# Adding touchdesigner project to Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-streaming, webcam, live-streaming, image-augmentation

I'd like to find a way to add a touchdesigner output to unity as a plane that displays the unity output?

The idea is to have a screen showing the webcam however if I use touchdesigner rather than a webcam texture I can add auto zoom and tracking which would help a lot.
Any advice would be appreciated or links to tutorials if they exist? I've been looking and struggling to find what I need.